# Make Json from model with gson in android studio

Tags: android-json

I have repeatedly searched for this on Google or other sources, but haven't found anything suitable for my problem, try to help me to resolve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Normal' java objects inside of your Model String, int, Date, etc are already handled by gson, but to deserialize custom objects inside of a model you'll need to register your own custom serialization.  Check out this:  https://futurestud.io/tutorials/gson-advanced-custom-deserialization-basics

Comment: I already have a model here, but I want to change the model to json, can you give an example with the code?

Comment: The link shows you how to make a custom deserializer

GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();

JsonDeserializer<UserDate> deserializer = ...; // will implement in a second  
gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(UserDate.class, deserializer);